# Supported Regions in Serverless Framework

Tags: next.js, serverless, aws-serverless

I am serving my `Next.js` with `Serverless` and `AWS Lambda` at the `ap-northeast-2` region.

My service is working well, but when I deployed it I would always see the below **Warning message**

> Warned - Region "ap-northeast-2" not in list of permitted regions: ["us-east-1","us-east-2","us-west-2","eu-west-1","eu-west-2","ap-northeast-1","ap-southeast-1","ap-southeast-2","eu-central-1"]

I understand they are only supporting the above list of regions.

But, my service is working now in the `ap-northeast-2` region.

So, I want to know what does it meaning and What could be problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you're seeing refers to the supported regions for the [Serverless Framework Dashboard](https://serverless.com/dashboard/), a free Development, Monitoring, and Deployment platform.
If you'd like to try the dashboard, you'd need to switch to a different region until support is added.

Comment: Oh, I got it. so they are not supporting the **Dashboard** with some regions only? If I don't need to use the **Dashboard**, that warning is just a text. is it right?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's just a small thing. haha.